# On the computation of natural logarithm in dimensional regularization

Tags: integration, regularization, dimensional-regularization

When calculating the integral

\begin{equation}
\int\frac{d^4q}{(2\pi)^4\left(q^2+\Delta+i\epsilon\right)^2}
\end{equation}

We encounter a term of $\ln\Delta$ and I am not sure how does one treat it properly since it has a dimension of $E^4$, so if we try to turn logarithm into power series we would encounter a problem by summing the terms of the dimension $E^{4n}$.

I do understand that the logarithm is coming from the limit of $\Delta^{\epsilon}$, while applying dimensional regularization, but I am not sure how to compute $\ln\Delta$ if we can compute the $\Delta$ (after integration over $du$, that is responsible for Feynman parametrization it won't disappear in some cases, if I did the integration correctly) with given variables.

Comment: Shouldn't the result of that integral have $\Delta$ included in a ratio with the dimensional scale $\mu$ if you are doing dimensional regularization?